# Is the TD-residual defined for timesteps $t$ past the length of the episode?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients, papers, temporal-difference-methods

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the state-space in a reinforcement learning problem where rewards are in $\mathbb{R}$, and let $V:\mathcal{S} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an approximate value function. Following [the GAE paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02438), the TD-residual with discount $\gamma \in [0,1]$ is defined as $\delta_t^V = r_t + \gamma V(s_{t + 1}) - V(s_t)$.

I am confused by the formula for the GAE-$\lambda$ advantage estimator, which is
$$
\hat{A}_t^{\text{GAE}(\gamma, \lambda)} = \sum_{l = 0}^\infty (\gamma \lambda)^l \delta_{t + l}^V.
$$

This seems to imply that $\delta_t^V$ is defined for $t > N$, where $N$ is the length of the current trajectory/episode. It looks like in implementations of this advantage estimator, it is just assumed that $\delta_t^V = 0$ for $t > N$, since the sums are finite. Is there a justification for this assumption? Or am I missing something here?